Python Flet error: takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
I am trying to create a Rock, Paper, Scissors application using Python and flet. I get:
TypeError: main.<locals>.rock() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

I don't understand what the error is telling me. I am trying to get it to change "choices_text" from "Player vs Computer" to whatever each entity chose ("Player" to player's choice, and "Computer" to whatever the randomizer selected for the computer.) Then "winner_textField" would output who won or if it was a tie.
Here is my code so far:
import flet as ft
import random

def main(page: ft.Page):

    ############ function ##################
    def rock():
        computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
        if computer == 'rock':
            choices_text.value = "Rock vs Rock"
            winner_textField.value = "It's a tie!"
        elif computer == "paper":
            choices_text.value = "Rock vs Paper"
            winner_textField.value = "Computer wins!"
        else:
            choices_text.value = "Rock vs Scissors"
            winner_textField.value = "You win!"
        page.update()

    def paper():
        computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
        if computer == 'rock':
            choices_text.value = "Paper vs Rock"
            winner_textField.value = "You win!"
        elif computer == "paper":
            choices_text.value = "Paper vs Paper"
            winner_textField.value = "It's a tie!"
        else:
            choices_text.value = "Paper vs Scissors"
            winner_textField.value = "Computer wins!"
        page.update()
    
    def scissors():
        computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
        if computer == 'rock':
            choices_text.value = "Scissors vs Rock"
            winner_textField.value = "Computer wins!"
        elif computer == "paper":
            choices_text.value = "Scissors vs Paper"
            winner_textField.value = "You win!"
        else:
            choices_text.value = "Scissors vs Scissors"
            winner_textField.value = "It's a tie!"
        page.update()
        
    def reset():
        choices_text.value = "Player vs Computer"
        winner_textField.value = " "
        page.update()

    ############# page setup ################
    page.title="Rock Paper Scissors"
    page.window_width = 500
    page.window_height = 700
    page.theme_mode = "light"
    page.window_center()
    page.vertical_alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.SPACE_EVENLY
    page.horizontal_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

    ########### page content ###############
    title_text = ft.Text("Rock Paper Scissors", color="BLUE", size=30)
    choices_text = ft.Text("Player vs Computer", color="BLACK", size=25)

    ########### output ###############
    winner_textField = ft.TextField(width=300, height=100, color="BLACK", text_size=20, text_align="center")    

    ########### input buttons ###############
    rock_button = ft.ElevatedButton(content=ft.ResponsiveRow([ft.Text("ROCK", size=20, text_align="center")]), width=150, height=100, bgcolor="BLUE", color="WHITE", on_click=rock)
    paper_button = ft.ElevatedButton(content=ft.ResponsiveRow([ft.Text("PAPER", size=20, text_align="center")]), width=150, height=100, bgcolor="BLUE", color="WHITE", on_click=paper)
    scissors_button = ft.ElevatedButton(content=ft.ResponsiveRow([ft.Text("SCISSORS", size=20, text_align="center")]), width=200, height=100, bgcolor="BLUE", color="WHITE", on_click=scissors)  

    ############ reset button ###############
    reset_button = ft.ElevatedButton(content=ft.ResponsiveRow([ft.Text("Reset", size=20, text_align="center")]), width=300, height=100, bgcolor="BLUE", color="WHITE", on_click=reset)


    page.add(
        title_text, 
        choices_text, 
        rock_button, 
        paper_button, 
        scissors_button, 
        winner_textField,
        reset_button
    )

ft.app(target=main)


When you use on_click= to specify a function to be called in response to a button click, I believe the click event itself is always passed as an argument.  So you can define the rock() function to accept an argument, and then just ignore it.

in flet the on_click will call the function specified with few details of the control. so, the function that is being called is like rock(e). change your function to take a dummy param and the error will be set.

Exactly! Also, if you don't plan to use the event e, you can use replace it with an underscore _ :)
